# Read a list of signed shorts from a binary file using the >> operator

Tags: c++, stream, short

Isn't this possible through the >> operator ?

Sources :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

The value of 's' remains the same : it doesn't seem to grab any number from the input stream.

```
vector<signed short> CReadFileTest::ReadIntegersFromFile( const char * filename )
{
    ifstream ifs(filename, ifstream::in, ifstream::binary);
    vector<signed short> vec ;
    if (ifs)
    {
        signed short s ;

        while (!ifs.eof())
        {
            ifs >> s;
            vec.push_back(s);
        }
        ifs.close();

    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Is your file text (with text representation of values like `-7 123   2`) or binary (with `sizeof(short)` bytes per value)? Anyway, your testing for EOF is wrong, and your non-testing for errors conceals everything which goes wrong (and if the file is binary, it will go wrong).

Comment: The file is in a binary form and yes you're right, testing through EOF is bad (the application returns, something very bad just happened :-); but I currently have no idea on how to make this exception visible.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a binary file you will have to use [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

Comment: He needs to use `read()` because he has binary data, not because he opened the file with newline-translation disabled.

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct, will fix my wording.